# How to destructure an array with the right Typescript typification?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I faced some difficulties with typescript destructuring array typification. Can't make array destructuring with typescript.

I got some data from a server. This data has the type (ISpecType[] | undefined)

```
interface ISpecType {
    id: string
    doughTypes: object[]
    sizes: object[]
    chosenDoughType: string
    chosenSize: number
    pizzaId: string
}

// omitted the fetch logic of getting data

// 'data' equals =
data = [
 {
  chosenDoughType: "Thin"
  chosenSize: 26
  doughTypes: (2) [{…}, {…}]
  id: "7p5Xca6DykcUkvE8A7P4p"
  pizzaId: "VYyLBL3l5JXhUAqXOb-rt"
  sizes: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
 }
]

// the code where the error comes up.
 const [single]: ISpecType[] | undefined = data
```

After that, I got this message:

```
ERROR in src/features/pizzas/PizzaSpecsButtons.tsx:30:11
TS2461: Type 'ISpecType[] | undefined' is not an array type.
    28 |         }),
    29 |     })
  > 30 |     const [single]: ISpecType[] | undefined = data
       |           ^^^^^^^^
```

The type of data mustn't be changed!

How to tackle it?

Comment: Well, you cannot destructure `undefined`.

Comment: I would write `const [single]: (ISpectType | undefined)[] | undefined = data??[]`, does that work for you?  If so, I could write up an answer explaining.  If not, why not?

Comment: A response from a server might be undefined, but a full data response is actually got well.

Comment: There is data like in the example above.

Comment: And it is worth nothing to insert a default empty array in a case of an undefined response.

Comment: I don't see how "it is worth nothing".  It is worth not having a runtime error; `let [foo] = undefined` will throw a type error at runtime, while `let [foo] = undefined ?? []` will at least give you an `undefined` value of `foo`.

Comment: The compiler runs well before any response comes back from a server. If the type of `data` is `ISpecType[] | undefined` then the compiler expects you to properly account for the undefined case.  You can do this as I showed above.  If you are sure that `data` will be of type `[ISpecType]`, then you should either change it or assert it.  Since you said "The type of data mustn't be changed!" then you could write `const [single] = data as [ISpecType]`, but then don't be surprised if that breaks at runtime if your assertion is incorrect.

Comment: What, specifically, is your goal?  To keep your code the same but suppress a TypeScript error?  Or to make your code type safe so that TypeScript does not issue an error in the first place?  Or something else?

Comment: @jcalz  This snippet `const [single]: (ISpectType | undefined)[] | undefined = data??[]` worked out. I would recommend you break this code down into an apart answer.

Comment: When I said, "it is worth nothing to insert a default empty array", I meant something that you(@jcalz) did .`data??[]` Isn't it safe enough?

Comment: Isn't *what* safe enough?  I don't think I understand you.

Comment: In case I get an undefined response from a server.

Comment: @jcalz, I don't understand this scrap `(ISpecType | undefined)[]` What does it mean?

Comment: I'm really not understanding your comments.  Could you be as explicit as possible?  What, specifically, do you mean by "And it is worth nothing to insert a default empty array in a case of an undefined response."?  If I've misinterpreted it, then please help me.

Comment: I can explain `(ISpecType | undefined)[]` when I write up my answer, if you do want an answer.  Do you?  I *think* that's what "This snippet ... worked out. I would recommend you break this code down into an apart answer." means.  Am I right?

Comment: @jcalz, When I wrote, "And it is worth nothing to insert a default empty array in a case of an undefined response." I actually meant "And this is not hard to write something like this": `data ?? []`. Getting a default empty array in case of an undefined response.

Comment: @jcalz, Yes, I want you to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible failure cases you need to consider when you write `const [single] = data`, if all you know about `data` at compile time is that it is of type  `ISpecType[] | undefined`.

---

First: `data` can be `undefined`.  If so, then the line `const [single] = data` will attempt to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `undefined`, which will result in a runtime TypeError. That's why the compiler is giving you an error.

In order to prevent this from happening, you can use the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to replace `undefined` with an empty array, so that `single` will be `undefined`:

```
const [single] = data ?? [];
```

But wait, when you check the type of `single`, the compiler thinks it is definitely `ISpecType` and not `ISpecType | undefined`:

```
// const single: ISpecType
```

Oops.  That brings us to the second failure case.

---

Second: `data` can be an empty array.  If so, then `const [single] = data` will end up making `single` undefined, but the compiler unfortunately does not catch this.  TypeScript give arrays a numeric [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), and traditionally assumes that if you index into an `Array<X>` with a numeric index, you'll get a value of type `X`.  Yes, it's possible for it to be `undefined`, but the compiler doesn't consider the possibility.  If you forget to check for `undefined`, you're likely to hit a runtime error even though the compiler thinks it's fine.  This has been a longstanding issue; see [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778).

And you can actually enable [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) to enable stricter checking, at which point things would work:

```
// with --noUncheckedIndexedAccess enabled
const [single] = data ?? [];
// const single: ISpecType | undefined
```

But this compiler option is not part of the standard [`--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) because it tends to be  annoying to use, and it affects your whole code base.  Instead of this I recommend providing an explicit `undefined` entry in your default array, so that the compiler is aware of the possibility:

```
// regardless of --noUncheckedIndexedAccess 
const [single] = data ?? [undefined]
// const single: ISpecType | undefined
```

---

Now you have a `single` of type `ISpecType | undefined` and the compiler is happy.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUAOEEBUCe2yA3gFDLLAAmAXMgM5hSgDm5yVA9gK4sAWBbPTqcARgCscYANoBddvWAAvCMORjJCGfIoI+nehBAARHv0EQ6jZiDa79hkOmWXkIbgFtR0dpmVK4VFoGJlZSAF9SUgB6aPUPYDBIKmQwPhQYCDA9ZAAbThZgBHUYZBYssFYOODA4KNjkAHIqGrhG5AgAR244XPpkAF5SBE4QRmraweRpdjIKewMjU14BQlcAIlw+UHWAGnYFx2cVOgAmADZ9+Y4zVaE6aWJw3ZJw2Sv56jp1gHZMAFYABoIODnYz4ADWCAAqhCAG4AUQAHABBH4ABQALJg9gdkH4lAEgt8AGoATXwABkAEKUgDMuX+AClAXxoSjOoCAPKiAC0UDAuOuihUakez1eLyeOmQkVkyDg-Qw2DwazkyAAPshuCAqBAYKAIFQANxREZjMDTTicTD0eUDCZwY3IBrQKCcKAAQhicQsTWVOAs6q1Or1BpARvaHm44z4cDhKDgTWk6HwXk4uQAdIloDUPbIABQASijWX0KTSNWQUCy3CgYwVIEokCgeagmbNo3G0j4Hg89sdyAA-EPprJTQ1zbG+3QA6rsJ2LdNFLZchABy1JiPpqH9YaqPJJ13LSuWGvZ1hA2tNdrdXuI1QgA)

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. That one helped me a lot. I appreciate it!